# SOAP stateful operation example

Tags: xml, soap, stateful

I have been told that the example at the following link, is a stateless SOAP operation.

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_example.asp

But now I'm looking for a stateful SOAP operation, similar to the example from the link.
The body of a stateful SOAP operation, does it include a state element  ?